# Is any percentage of the regular solar wind that penetrates into Earth's atmosphere able to reach Earth's surface?

Tags: solar-wind

Is any percentage of the regular solar wind charged ions able to penetrate the earth atmosphere?
 if so, can it be detected or measured on the surface of earth at sea level?

Comment: I believe that the earths magnetic field shields almost all of the solar wind, but I am no expert in this field.

Comment: True, but does it shield 100%? I'm interested in knowing if any percentage still penetrates the atmosphere and reach earth surface.

Comment: The answer to this question, if in the affirmative, may have very significant ramifications for the future of renewable unlimited energy resources.

Comment: @MohsenKadoura the Sun is hardly an unlimited source...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Some of particles follow the van Allen belts and create these:
[image: I hope you know what these are!]

I am not 100% sure, but I do not believe that solar wind particles reach the surface of earth, and if they do they are probably indistinguishable from other earth-made particles. In order to really study the solar wind, we had to go into space with our instruments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is still doesn't answer my question for any percentage of the charged particles of the solar wind reaching the earth surface. Usually important and unexpected facts in physics are discovered when scientists do not assume the apparent or logical path deduced from existing facts, and this what keeps science and humanity progressing. The physical world around us follows its own logic and rules which at many occasions come as a complete surprise to the human mind (and it's not only in quantum physics this happens).

Comment: @MohsenKadoura: If you want an *exact* percentage, then the answer is: there is not a person who can tell you. You do realize that the reason we had to go to space to observe the solar wind directly was because we *weren't* seeing them on earth, right?

Comment: Actually some percentage of the solar wind does penetrate the atmosphere reaching us here on earth (refer to your beautiful photos of the auroras,thanks for these by the way) still some of these solar wind charged ions reach earth surface along with a percentage of cosmic rays. It's these that should be measured as they represent the source of radiant energy utilized by the Godfather of the modern electrical system used today all over the world.The patent registered in the patent office of New York,1901 :teslauniverse.com: nikola-tesla-patents-685,957 utilization-of-radiant-energy

Comment: @MohsenKadoura: I figured it was some bunk free-energy scheme you were after. Do you really & honestly think that no one has tried to put Tesla's patent into practice? Of course it's been tried, and it has not lived up to its expectations. Solar power does significantly better than Tesla's "radiant energy" scheme for generating usable energy.

Comment: That's why I was inquiring about the exact percentage as this would be a proper debunking of Tesla's device. You can't dismiss any electrical device invented by the inventor who practically laid the basis of our current electrical system supplying electrical power to virtually every appliance we are using now! To do this without violating objective scientific judgement you need actual scientific data and measurements. As for these who put Tesla's patent to the test and failed,references please, as I found none, except for unqualified amateurs.

Comment: @MohsenKadoura: The fact that we're not using his device is proof enough for me. If you want "actual scientific data and measurements" to disprove it, then go out and build his device and watch it fail.

Comment: As this is a scientifically inclined  physics forum, discussions should be of the same caliber, scientific and objective. It's not a personal argument, so personal comments are irrelevant. Sorry to waste my time here.

Comment: We deal with [mainstream physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site/4539#4539) here and "free energy" scheme constitute as non-mainstream.

Comment: Also, what "personal comment" are you saying is irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

Not of solar origin, but cosmic rays do reach the earth's surface, and computer equipment is engineered with this in mind.

Also, [something interesting about what may happen when the magnetic field goes through a reversal phase](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn4985-solar-wind-to-shield-earth-during-pole-flip.html#.UnrYV1QhDoE)

Comment: Please note that you should qualify, there are electron  neutrinos from the sun which are cosmic rays and have been seen in neutrino detectors .

Comment: Interesting, particularly the link. It has been known for some time that the ecological effect of pole reversal seems to be very mild indeed.